# 登録日別にカウントする方法がわかりません。

Tags: cakephp

```
$sql = "SELECT regdate, Count(photoid) AS cnt
        FROM tblphoto
        GROUP BY regdate
        ORDER BY regdate DESC";
```

こちらのSQL文をcakephp3で書く場合どうなるのでしょうか？
登録日別でカウントし、登録日、登録件数の一覧を表示させたいと思っています。

2017/11/02

こちらで実装できました。
ありがとうございました。

```
->select([
'regdate',
'cnt' => 'count(*)',
　　])
　　->group([
　　'regdate'
　　])
　　->order([
　　'regdate'=>'Desc'
　　])
　　->all();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

どうでしょうか。

```
$query = $tblphoto->find()
->select([
  'regdate', 'cnt' => $this->find()->func()->count('photoid')
])
->group('regdate')
->order(['regdate' => 'DESC']);
```

下記リンクを参考に書いてみました。テストはしていませんので、ちゃんと動くかわかりませんが。。
試してみてください。

[cakephp3 cookbook](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/ja/orm/query-builder.html)
[本家stackoverflowの質問](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29499893/how-do-you-use-count-with-findlist-in-cakephp-3)

Comment: コードの中身はみてませんがそのコードだと文法的に問題があるのでは？

Comment: たしかに、問題ありました。指摘ありがとうございます。修正してみました。